# Linker error when building from makefile

Tags: makefile, mingw, gnu-make, mingw-w64

I am trying to build a project consisting of sources distributed in various subdirectories e.g.

```
Project root
├───build
└───src
    │   main.cpp
    │
    ├───ui
    │       more files
    │
    └───core
            more files
```

Here are the relevant parts of the makefile I am using:

```
EXT       := cpp

SRC_DIR   := src/ui src src/core
SOURCES   := $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(sdir)/*.$(EXT)))
OBJECTS   := $(SOURCES:.$(EXT)=.o)

BIN       := program

$(BIN): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -mwindows $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

This results in the following error message: `undefined reference to WinMain` presumably because it has trouble finding the `main.o` file that contains the main function.

Would moving all the object files to the `build` folder solve this problem and what's the best way to do this?

Comment: It should work if you remove the $(OBJECTS) target. The default target will use `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<`.

Comment: @ssbssa that works fine. If you want to also move the object files however you would need an explicit rule right?

Comment: I think you mean ike this: `objdir/%.o: %.cpp ; $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@`

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is here:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

You have made *all* sources prerequisites of *each* object. And `$<` picks the first source. So when Make tries to build any object file (including `main.o`), it compiles the first source file in the list (`src/ui/someFile.cpp`). it then tries to link several identical object files (with different names), and finds many things missing.

Look into [vpath](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search), and see its use in other questions on this site about using source files in different directories. And yes, putting all object files into one directory (e.g. `objects/`) is a good idea.

The deeper problem is that you did not start small. You should have tried to build a single object file, noticed that the command was wrong, and attacked *that* problem.

Comment: I had a working makefile before but then I needed to organize the source code in different directories and that's when things broke down. You are right though, I probably bit off more than I could chew.